# How to retrieve data from multiple tables in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have two tables and i would like to retrieve data from them and pass it to my table.

For this I've created 2 models with an one to one relationship:

[Adress]

```
class Adress extends Model
{    
     public function KontoKorrent()
     {
         return $this->hasOne(KontoKorrent::class, 'Adresse');
     }
}
```

[KontoKorrent]

```
class KontoKorrent extends Model
{
     public function Adresse()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo(Adress::class,'Adresse');
     }
}
```

My controller look like this:

```
class AdressesController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
    $adresses = Adress::with('KontoKorrent')->paginate(2);
      return view('welcome', compact('adresses'));

   }
}
```

When I use `tinker`
App\Adress::
Every `adress` has relation to the `kontokorrent`. This is working.

```
  App\Adress {#698
         Adresse: "3030",
         Anrede: "Company",
         Name1: "A Company Name",
         LieferStrasse: "Dummystreet",
         KontoKorrent: App\KontoKorrent {#704
           Location: "1",
           Adresse: "3030",
           Kto: "S0043722",
```

In my view:

```
<ul>
  @foreach($adresses as $adress)
    <li>{{ $adress->Name1 }}</li>    //this is working
    <li>{{ $adress->KontoKorrent->Kto }}</li>  //this is NOT working
  @endforeach
</ul>

{{ $adresses->links() }}
```

The relation is showing me an error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you are getting:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Is related to some `Adress` model that doesn't have a `KontoKorrent`, then your `$adress->KontoKorrent` returns `null`, and null isn't a object, that the reason of the message.

To fix it, you should do an `if` to check if `adress` have the relationship:

```
<ul>
  @foreach($adresses as $adress)
    <li>{{ $adress->Name1 }}</li>    //this is working
    <li>
        @if($adress->KontoKorrent)
            {{ $adress->KontoKorrent->Kto }}
        @else
            <!-- Put something here if you want, otherwise remove the @else -->
        @endif
    </li>  //this is NOT working
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

This can be shortened to:

```
{{ $adress->KontoKorrent ? $adress->KontoKorrent : 'the else content' }}
```

or in PHP >= 7.0, you can use the [null coalesce](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) operator:

```
{{ $adress->KontoKorrent ?? 'the else content' }}
```

Comment: in fact i had some null entries. Thanks this solved my problem